# how are elasticsearch bool queries calculated

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a "bool" query with three "should" clauses.  If something matches all three clauses the explain show the score as a sum of the score of each clauses.  If it matches only two clauses, the score is a product of 2/3 and the sum of the two clauses.

I don't understand this behaviour.  If I'm only matching two of three I'll naturally have a relatively lower score (unless one of those clauses is a better match).  If this the expected results?

If I wanted, is there a way to sum the scores without this "normalization" factor?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer - it's called query coordination
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#coord

it seems I can set the disable_coord to ignore that compensation.